# why does it panic at line 12?

Tags: rust

```
use std::io;
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut s).unwrap();
    
    let mut a = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut a).unwrap();
    
    let q = s.trim().parse::<i32>().unwrap();
    let t = a.split("");
    for v in t {
        let p = v.trim().parse::<i32>().unwrap();
        println!("{}", q+p)
    }
}
```

I don't get why this unwrap panics. `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: Empty }

Comment: What you input is relevant to the question please provide either how you run this (including inputs when running) or preferably replace the `read_line` calls with `String`s containing it. See [mre] for further tips how to improve this question.

Comment: The error message is fairly clear, you try to parse an `Empty` string into an integer and that's not valid.

Comment: That’s because it’s an `unwrap` dude.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error message you've pasted says it all:

```
ParseIntError { kind: Empty }
```

It seems you're trying to parse an empty string, but that's not really a valid integer.

The string value depends on the user input. So your code might happen to work, depending on what the user has entered. But, clearly, the code doesn't handle the cases when the user input is not "correct". Calling `.unwrap()` (as well as `.expect(...)`) is mostly intended for cases where you are sure there can be no error or when there isn't really much you could do about the error and for simple programs that usually means just halting the program execution.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to `.split("")`?

What are you expecting the user to input as I think that's the center of your problem.  If I change it to `.split(",")` and type in 2 numbers with a comma between them, it seems to work as probably intended.  I think the issue is that you're attempting to split a number on an empty character and it's causing issues.